# Anybody get USB working in Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: keyboard, usb, iot, raspberry-pi2, windows-10

I got the **WinIoT** booted up and can communicate with it using **PowerShell**, but connecting a keyboard/mouse to the USB ports just doesn't work.

Is there a trick I don't know? The FAQ lists USB keyboard / mouse as supported devices, so I suspect it's me.

Comment: I'm up and running with keyboard and mouse (Corsair K60/Logitech G500). I've tried a couple of things that didn't work - Keysonic 540RF, Wacom Bamboo Touch. Could be device-specific niggles perhaps?

Comment: Okay, I'll swap out a few different models/brands to see if I can find something that works.  Thanks!

Comment: The KeySonic decided to fire up the other day, so it's only the Bamboo that's failing. I found the IoT Browser sample project helpful for testing inputs.

Comment: I'm using a Logitech K120 and it keeps repeating keypresses and missing others. Very frustrating. This is the sort of thing I would have thought Windows would have nailed.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems related to Keyboard and Mouse. Not all keyboard and mouse are supported. Either they don't work or behave strangely.
Following are the make working in my setup:

1. Keyboard : DELL USB Business Keyboard KB212
2. Mouse: Microsoft Optical mouse Model 1113
3. Wifi Adaptor: Raspberry Pi Wifi Adapter (Claimed to be only wifi adapter works with Raspberry Pi)
4. Bluetooth Dongle: Bluetooth CSR 4.0 A10 dongle

Windows and Raspberry Pi... Long way to go.